# Right inverse of a product of two right invertible operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, pseudoinverse

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A,B\in \mathcal{B}\left( H\right) $ be right
invertibe.

Can every right inverse of $AB$ be written as a product $CD$ where $C$
(resp. $D$) is a right inverse of $B$ (resp. $A$) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes in any unital algebra $\mathscr A$.

**Theorem**.  If $a$ and $b$ are right invertible elements in
$\mathscr A$, and
$u$ is any right inverse of $ab$, then it is possible to write
$u=cd$, where $c$ is a right inverse of $b$, and $d$ is a right
inverse of $a$.

*Proof*. Given $u$,  let $d=bu$, and notice that
$$
  ad = abu = 1,
  $$
so $d$ is indeed a right inverse of $a$.
Next pick any right inverse of $b$, say $c_0$, and set
$$
  c=c_0+(1-c_0b)ua.
  $$
We then have that
$$
  bc= bc_0+(b-bc_0b)ua = 1,
  $$
so $c$ is a right inverse of $b$.   Moreover
$$
  cd=
  \big (c_0+(1-c_0b)ua\big )bu = $$$$ =
  c_0bu+(1-c_0b)uabu = $$$$ =
  c_0bu+(1-c_0b)u = u,
  $$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much